# android camera2 preview is less focused than default camera

Tags: android, preview, camera2

Preview quality is not as good as default camera app. Check difference in hair in this [link](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1d0TiO8TCEWNKRyCe-xdU7Rr3kWSfq-u7Li4m-ywlPdU/edit?usp=sharing).

I implemented camera2 with help of [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic).
Both images are 4:3 ratio. I think is something to do with CaptureRequest that you set for camera.

`CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                  CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
                               mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);`
But I just can't get it to work like default camera.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this? I've been facing the same problem.